# Python matplotlib : how include a customized color list in a plt plot markerfacecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I think it's an easy one but I can't figure out how to make it:

I have a list of colors that I want to add in the markerfacecolor of a plt.plot

> colors= ['#003f5c','#444e86','#955196','#dd5182','#ff6e54','#ffa600']

Now to handle this color list in the other graphs of my figure I did:

- seaborn stripplot :   palette=sns.color_palette(colors)
- matplotlib hlines : colors=colors

But anything I try to include my 'colors' list in markerfacecolor of the plt.plot seems to fail

Any idea ?

[image]

```
# create rank
ranks = merged_df.groupby("region")["Value"].mean().fillna(0).sort_values(ascending=True)[::1].index
# for the hlines later
range_plot = range(0,len(ranks))

#Create figure
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

# define colors  https://learnui.design/tools/data-color-picker.html#palette
colors= ['#003f5c','#444e86','#955196','#dd5182','#ff6e54','#ffa600']
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
sns.set_context("paper")

# Set the font to be serif, rather than sans
sns.set(font='serif')
# Make the background white, and specify the
# specific font family
sns.set_style("white", {
        "font.family": "serif",
        "font.serif": ["Times", "Palatino", "serif"]})

#Create stripplot
ax = sns.stripplot(x='Value',
              y='region',
              data=merged_df,
              palette=sns.color_palette(colors),
              size=6,
              linewidth=0.4,
              alpha=.15,
              zorder=1,
              order = ranks)
#Create Conditional means
ax = plt.plot(merged_df.groupby("region")["Value"].mean().fillna(0).sort_values(ascending=True),
              range_plot,
              "o",
              markersize=18,
              markerfacecolor=colors,
              markeredgewidth=0.5,
              markeredgecolor='grey',
              zorder=3)

# add median line
ax = plt.axvline(merged_df.Value.mean(),
            color='grey',
            linestyle='dashed',
            linewidth=1,
            zorder=0)
plt.text(x=merged_df.Value.mean()+1,
         y=-0.1,
         s= 'Worldwide average: {number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=merged_df.Value.mean(),digits=0))
# Add category line
mean = merged_df.Value.mean()
x_arr = merged_df.groupby("region")["Value"].mean().fillna(0).sort_values(ascending=True)
plt.hlines(y=range_plot,
           xmin=mean,
           xmax=x_arr,
           colors=colors,
           linewidth=3,
           zorder=3)

# Add the title
plt.text(x= -6.5,
         y= -0.75,
         s = '{}'.format(merged_df.Indicator.iloc[0]),
         fontsize = 22)
# We change the aspect of ticks label and labels 
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Student to teacher ratio',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('')

# Add the source
plt.text(x= merged_df.Value.max()-25,
         y= 6.4,
         s = 'Data: UNESCO institute for statistics',fontsize = 12, color = 'grey')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("UNESCO.jpeg", transparent=True, dpi=300)
```

Comment: `ax.scatter` can take an array of colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by Paul I replaced plt.plot by plt.scatter and was able to change the marker aesthetic as desired:
[image]